# Bootstrap 5 Hamburger Animation not working

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu, bootstrap-5

**SOLVED**
Ok I solved the problem :)

The problem was:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open'); //Chrome expert mode says $ is not a function
    });
});
```

So I solved the problem with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

I hope it helps another of you too :)
Thanks for try to helping.

**Question was:**

I need help with some animations.
I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I want to create a hamburger menu animation.

The following code snippets are from my webpage, but the animations don't work.
The code snippets are sourced from: https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/911054#html-tab-view

HTML CODE:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-mobile">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo"/>
    
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navigation"aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<div class="animated-hamburger"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">

<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 navbar-right nav-item">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigation" onclick="toggleMenu() />
</ul>
<div class="collapse-show-bottom"></div>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
.animated-hamburger {
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 3px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border-radius: 9px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span {
    background: #f3e5f5 !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 8px !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0% !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    top: 21px !important;
    left: 8px !important;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it not javascript?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: `$(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    });
});` 

Seem more like JavaScript than Java

Comment: yeah sorry I've edit my text. This code is in my main.js

Comment: @BudaÖrs yea it's JQuery

Comment: could you tell us more what you expect and what you have ?

Comment: I uploaded 2 pictures. The first picture is the hamburger menu normal (closed) and the second picture should actually be an x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add JQuery libs to let the script work,

**EDITED**: added event to close menu after clicking outside.

here is an example;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function() {
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    });
    
    $(document).click(function(event) {
      var tover = $(event.target);
    if ($('.animated-hamburger').hasClass('open') && !tover.hasClass('animated-hamburger')) {
    $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    }
    });

});
```

```css
.animated-hamburger {
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 3px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border-radius: 9px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span {
    background: #f3e5f5 !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left center !important;
    transform-origin: left center !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 8px !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0% !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
    
.animated-hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    top: 21px !important;
    left: 8px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- JUST ADD THIS LINE -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ENDS HERE -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-mobile">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo"/>
    
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navigation"aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<div class="animated-hamburger"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">

<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 navbar-right nav-item">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigation" onclick="toggleMenu() />
</ul>
<div class="collapse-show-bottom"></div>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't understand why the snipped code works for you and absolutely not for me.
Is it because I am using this code in a php website for joomla?

Comment: @dan3er open console log to check errors ?

Comment: I have solved this problem but now it's the next:

When I click on a link in the hamburger menu, the "x" remains there. If I click with the mouse or with the touch on the smartphone on another point of the website it goes back.

Comment: @dan3er you have to set a statement to hide the menu when clicking outside it or using it's content

Comment: I tried siblings, but it doesn't work.
```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').addClass('open').siblings().removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: @dan3er i'll edit my answer with the function;

Comment: thanks. It works but only for 3-4 times. If i use the hamburger menu for more then 3-4 times it doesn't show the .open class

Comment: there is no rule to use it 3-4 times, it might be a late response only from your browser side, as long as i don't have any problem with it

Comment: maybe on chrome browser? firefox works better but on iphone (safari) it works like chrome

Comment: can you tell me why the hamburger animation doesn't work every time on this page https://pr-designs.de ? If the page opens and the navigation is top, the navigation works but the animation does not and that is often on the page.

Answer (score 0):

[hamburger menu normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez1jM.png)

[hamburger menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDVGf.png)

The hamburger menu should become an x ​​when you click it.

Comment: does this all your problem ?

Comment: you should use Jquery libs to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem :)

The problem was:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open'); //Chrome expert mode says $ is not a function
    });
});
```

So I solved the problem with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.navbar-toggler-button').on('click', function () {
  
      $('.animated-hamburger').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

I hope it helps another of you too :)
Thanks for try to helping.

Answer (score 0):

Next problem....

When I click on a link in the hamburger menu, the "x" remains there. If I click with the mouse or with the touch on the smartphone on another point of the website it goes back.